# Do while loop displaying contents 3 times in cmd

Tags: java

I have the below program and while running it, I am getting the menu printed 3 times. I was expecting only one and immediately prompt for input.

```
class whileexample2
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        char i;
        int a = 100;
        int b = 20;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("select your choice");
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            System.out.println("(1) Additon");
            System.out.println("(2) Subtraction");
            System.out.println("(3) Multiplication");
            System.out.println("(4) Division");
            i = (char) System.in.read();
        } while (i < '1' || i > '4');
        System.out.println("\n");
        switch(i)
        {
            case '1':
            {
                System.out.println("Result of addition is: " + (a + b));
                break;
            }
            case '2':
            {
                System.out.println("Result of subtraction is: " + (a - b));
                break;
            }
            case '3':
            {
                System.out.println("Result of multiplication is: " + (a * b));
                break;
            }
            case '4':
            {
                System.out.println("Result of division is: " + (a / b));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

> select your choice
>   ---------------------
>   (1) Additon
>   (2) Subtraction
>   (3) Multiplication
>   (4) Division
>   7    //incorrect input, thus show menu again, but it will be printed 3 times
>   select your choice
>   ---------------------
>   (1) Additon
>   (2) Subtraction
>   (3) Multiplication
>   (4) Division
>   select your choice
>   ---------------------
>   (1) Additon
>   (2) Subtraction
>   (3) Multiplication
>   (4) Division
>   select your choice
>   ---------------------
>   (1) Additon
>   (2) Subtraction
>   (3) Multiplication
>   (4) Division
>   2
>
> Result of subtraction is: 80

Comment: Is it because you print the menu out inside the do...while loop?

Comment: @BretC: I want to repeat the menu upon entering the invalid input and hence I print it inside do.. while loop. But not sure why it displays 3 times on invalid input enter. When entering right input, it works fine as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
i = (char) System.in.read();
```

This line is causing you issues.  You are entering more than just a number in this stream, since when you hit "Enter", you are inserting a carriage return to the stream, and then a newline .  This is causing your while loop to go through three times, since the stream it is reading contains the characters '7' '\r', and '\n'.

Considering using a scanner instead and checking only the first character of input instead.  Scanner tends to be more reliable and platform independent:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class WhileExample2{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        char i;
        int a=100;
        int b=20;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("select your choice");
            System.out.println("---------------------");
            System.out.println("(1) Additon");
            System.out.println("(2) Subtraction");
            System.out.println("(3) Multiplication");
            System.out.println("(4) Division");
            i = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
        }while(i < '1' || i > '4');
        //rest of code
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest `kb.nextLine()` to read everything until up to the return. (Also you declare the scanner twice in your example.)

Answer (score 0):

The switch statement should be inside the Do-While loop